# Duplicate Class while using firebase and google-cloud-texttospeech

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, text-to-speech

I am having an android project using firestore, firebase-auth and FCM . Now when I am adding google-cloud-texttospeech to my project I am getting 'Duplicate class' error

Here is my dependencies

```
//Firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.1.0"
    /*implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$rootProject.crashlytics"*/
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0"
    // Ad-mob
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0"
    implementation ("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-texttospeech:0.97.0-beta")
```

This is the error I am getting while building the project.

```
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AdviceOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AnnotationsProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProviderOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirementOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRule found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)
```

Now I understand the firebase and google-cloud-texttospeech is using same classes inside there dependencies.
So I tried to exclude those by

```
implementation ("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-texttospeech:0.97.0-beta"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.api.grpc', module: 'proto-google-common-protos'
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-lite'
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
}
```

Then the app is building but crashes while speech synthesising

```
2019-07-03 20:04:15.861 24851-24851/package.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: package.dev, PID: 24851
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3;
at com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.create(TextToSpeechClient.java:101)
at package_name.tts.TextSpeachAPI.<init>(TextSpeachAPI.kt:8)
at package_name.ui.home.sofar.WordDetailsVM.speak(WordDetailsVM.kt:318)
at package_name.ui.home.sofar.WordDetailsFragment$listeners$11.onClick(WordDetailsFragment.kt:264)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/package_name.dev-apgPZPeLvH3LUXKWw2gBbg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/package_name.dev-apgPZPeLvH3LUXKWw2gBbg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.create(TextToSpeechClient.java:101) 
at package_name.tts.TextSpeachAPI.<init>(TextSpeachAPI.kt:8) 
at package_name.ui.home.sofar.WordDetailsVM.speak(WordDetailsVM.kt:318) 
at package_name.ui.home.sofar.WordDetailsFragment$listeners$11.onClick(WordDetailsFragment.kt:264) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: can you post full gradle dependencies ?

Comment: My bad,  I just updated the proper versions in the question.

Comment: i am asking because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37677446/10182897) says if user uses different jar it generate conflict

Comment: I agree, but the problem is not with gradle. firebase and google-cloud-texttospeech is using same classes in different dependencies. I tried to exclude those and then the text to speech in crashing.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced such a problem when using "google cloud speech".
In the use of "firestore" and "google cloud speech", I showed duplicate classes in "protobuf-java", "protobuf-lite", "proto-google-common-protos" and "protolite-well-known-types" I solved the problem by unzipping the jar files and creating a new jar file with no duplicate classes. Please refer to the github project I posted below.

https://github.com/ivso0001/GoogleCloudSpeechAndFirebaseIntegration

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
android{
  ...
  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}
dependencies{
  ...
  implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.41.0-alpha'){
        exclude module: 'protobuf-javalite'
        exclude module: 'protobuf-java'
        exclude module: 'proto-google-common-protos'
    }
}
```

Ref:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/SpeechRecognitionClient/app/build.gradle

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64226363/8459761

Comment: This doesn't work for `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-texttospeech:2.28.0`