# Duplicate classes occur when adding Google Cloud Language library to Android app

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, dependencies, google-natural-language

I am encounter a problem when I try to build the Android app and it appear error. The error appear after I add the last line in Gradle Build file (the natural language library).
Below is my gradle build file code

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' version '0.5'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myvolunteer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform

    // Declare the dependencies for the Firebase Cloud Messaging and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.1'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    //Circle Image View
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'


    //Cloud-lang,but it causes duplicate classes occur.
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:2.1.2'


}
```

Some of the error that I get when try to build the project in Android Studio (it's too much I can't put all of them here)

```
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.5.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.5.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.cloud.audit.AuthenticationInfo$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.5.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.longrunning.Operation$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.5.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.5.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
```

How can I resolve this problem? I really need to add the Google Natural Language library to my app.

**Updated: The attempt that I have tried but failed:**

[Firebase Android: Duplicate Protobuf classes found in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63329045/16326040)

[Duplicate Class while using firebase and google-cloud-texttospeech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875513/duplicate-class-while-using-firebase-and-google-cloud-texttospeech)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate classes exception means that one of your dependencies uses implicitly the older or newer (with +) version of some library you also use in your project,

To resolve this issue you may add such block of code (put your library version after 'force') to your build.gradle file (Module:app):

```
configurations {
   all {
      resolutionStrategy {
          // do not upgrade above 3.12.0 to support API < 21 while server uses
          // COMPATIBLE_TLS, or okhttp3 is used in project
          force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
          force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
      }
   }
}
```

You may also exclude some group from your dependencies. For a single dependency you way write:

```
dependencies {

    // example
    implementation('log4j:log4j:1.2.15') {
        exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
    }
}
```